# Why does Typescript allow assignability for a generic type parameter in a contravariant position?

Tags: typescript, variance, contravariant

In the following code, the type parameter `T` appears in a contravariant position in the `Setter` type. Why does typescript allow the assignment in a way that seems to break variance rules?

```
type Setter1<T> = {
    set(val: T): void
}

function f1(x: Setter1<'a'>): void {
    const y: Setter1<string> = x // no compile error. why?
}
```

On the other hand, the below code does have a compile error (which is what I would expect).

```
type Setter2<T> = {
    set: (val: T) => void
}

function f2(x: Setter2<'a'>): void {
    const y: Setter2<string> = x // compile error. good!
}
```

Comment: Method parameters in TS are *bivariant*, not contravariant. It's not type safe but that's the way it is.